# C - Two child process with same parent and calling function server()

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I have this program that "simulates" a parking lot. I have been searching a lot and I couldn't find anything that really fits on my problem. But if you know a similar question that could answer mine, send me the link! :)

This is my main, with the second child process already created (I don't think I need to put comments here, it's only doing a fork(), then inside the parent it does a second fork(), creating another child with the same parent. Right?):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char spots[25];

main()
{
 int    descritor, descritor2, //gets the fork's pid
 pipe1[2],  // comunicacao pai -> filho
 pipe2[2];  // comunicacao filho -> pai
 char msg[10] = "";


if (pipe(pipe1)<0 || pipe(pipe2) <0)
{ 
    printf("Erro na chamada PIPE");
    exit(0);
}


if ((descritor = fork()) <0)
{ 
    printf("Erro na chamada FORK");
    exit(0);
}

else if (descritor > 0)  
{   
    descritor2 = fork(); 

    if(descritor2 == 0)
    {
        strcpy(msg,"CHILD 2");
        fprintf(stdout, msg);

        close(pipe1[1]); 
        close(pipe2[0]);  

        server(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]); 

        close(pipe1[0]); 
        close(pipe2[1]);  
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (descritor2 > 0) 
    {           
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);  

        client(pipe2[0], pipe1[1]); 

        close(pipe1[1]); 
        close(pipe2[0]);  
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (descritor2 < 0)
    {
        printf("Erro na chamada FORK");
        exit(0);
    }

} 

else 
{   
    strcpy(msg,"CHILD 1");
    fprintf(stdout, msg);

    close(pipe1[1]); 
    close(pipe2[0]);  

    server(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]);  

    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);  
    exit(0);

 } 
}
```

I have the parent process which is calling the client function below:

```
client (int readfd, int writefd)

//    readfd, leitura do pipe2[0]
//    writefd; escrita no pipe1[1]

{
 char buff[2];
 int i, pos = 0;

 system("clear");

 populating(); //this is a function I call only this time to populate my global char array with the spots 1-25
 printing(pos); //this one I use to update and to print the spots

 while(1)
 {
    printf("\nDigite sua vaga -> "); //type the spot
    gets(buff);
    write(writefd, buff, 10); //sends to server (child)

    read(readfd,buff,10); //reads from server (child)
    pos = atoi(buff); //parses to int, because I think I can't write() read() int data, and I need to use this data (pos) to update my spots

    if(spots[pos] == 0) //check if it's occupied
    {
        sleep(1); 
        system("clear");
        printing(0); //passes the value 0 to update spots[0] which contains nothing
        printf("\nEsta vaga esta ocupada!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Vaga %s reservada.\n",buff);

        sleep(1); 
        system("clear");
        printing(pos); //the function printing is only a loop that gets the value typed earlir and do spots[pos] = 0. then print the spots updated
    }       
 }

}
```

Then I have my server function:

```
server(int readfd, int writefd)
// readfd, leitura do pipe1[0]
//   writefd; escrita no pipe2[1]

{
 char buff[2];
 int n, fd, pos;


while(1)    
{
    read(readfd,buff,10); //read the spot
    pos = atoi(buff);

 if(pos > 25 || pos < 1)//checks if it's in range
 {          
    while(pos > 25 || pos < 1)
    {
        printf("\nVaga indisponivel. Digite novamente\n");
        printf("-> ");      
        gets(buff); 
        pos = atoi(buff);
    }
}

 write(writefd, buff, 10); //sends the spot back to the parent
}


}
```

So, based on this, I have a few questions and would appreciate if someone could help with them.

I want to make the two child process "fight" for the cpu, but I noticed that I'm getting stuck with only one child. Is that because of the "while(1)"? If so, how could I do a loop to keep the program running then? Or the problem is that I'm using two pipes for 3 processes? (pipe1 I read from one side and write from the other, and vice-versa).

I also noticed that the messages "CHILD 1" or "CHILD 2" only prints when I type an invalid spot... Why is that?

So, summing all this up, I want to keep the two child processes running and getting the spot typed on father "concurrently", running one child process a few times, then the other, and so on. And seeing if it's on range. I would also want to see if the spot == 0, but this doesn't work on the child process, I don't know why, so I left this on the parent.

It's working with no errors at all, but the problem is that I think there's only one child running per execution... I want to make both of them run.

If you need additional information in order to understand my situation or something else, ask me!

Comment: Not sure it has anything to do with your problem but I think you must check the value returned by `read`

Comment: BTW: Never use `gets` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: hmmm, I don't know if I get your point, but, the program it's working fine, no errors at all. I just want to make the two child process work, not only one. Understand?

Comment: What sould I use instead of gets? Thanks

Comment: Use `fgets` .... but read the provided link :-)

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you

Comment: also, `int main(void)`; It is about time to stop using constructs that were made obsolescent in 1989 or deprecated in 1999.

Comment: hey guys, I replaced the gets(buff) with fgets(buff, 2, stdin), and it kinda bugged my program. Is running like if i typed a valid and invalid spot at the same time... any ideia why?

Comment: My first idea is that `fgets` stores the `\n` so you might have to extend `buff` to 3 char and remove the `\n`